# Line from bash command output stored in variable as string

Tags: linux, string, bash, output

I'm trying to find a solution to a problem analog to this one:

```
#command_A

A_output_Line_1
A_output_Line_2
A_output_Line_3

#command_B

B_output_Line_1
B_output_Line_2
```

Now I need to compare **A_output_Line_2** and **B_output_Line_1** and echo "Correct" if they are equal and "Not Correct" otherwise.

I guess the easiest way to do this is to copy a line of output in some variable and then after executing the two commands, simply compare the variables and echo something.
This I need to implement in a bash script and any information on how to get certain line of output stored in a variable would help me put the pieces together.
Also, it would be cool if anyone can tell me not only how to copy/store a line, but probably just a word or sequence like : line 1, bytes 4-12, stored like string in a variable.

I am not a complete beginner but also not anywhere near advanced linux bash user. Thanks to any help in advance and sorry for bad english!

Comment: While registering on SO, there ought to be a question: `How did you come to know about us?`

Comment: `grep`,  `sed`, `awk` and maybe `cut` are commands that are helpful for doing what you want. The man pages should help and a lot of examples for nearly everything are shared across the internet. :)

Answer (score 2):

An easier way might be to use `diff`, no?

Something like:

```
command_A > command_A.output
command_B > command_B.output
diff command_A.output command_B.output
```

This will work for comparing multiple strings.

But, since you want to know about single lines (and words in the lines) here are some pointers:

```
# first line of output of command_A
command_A | head -n 1
```

The `-n 1` option says only to use the first line (default is 10 I think)

```
# second line of output of command_A
command_A | head -n 2 | tail -n 1
```

that will take the first two lines of the output of `command_A` and then the last of those two lines. Happy times :)

You can now store this information in a variable:

```
export output_A=`command_A | head -n 2 | tail -n 1`
export output_B=`command_B | head -n 1`
```

And then compare it:

```
if [ "$output_A" == "$output_B" ]; then echo 'Correct'; else echo 'Not Correct'; fi
```

To just get parts of a string, try looking into `cut` or (for more powerful stuff) `sed` and `awk`.

Also, just learing a good general purpose scripting language like `python` or `ruby` (even `perl`) can go a long way with this kind of problem.

Comment: Could be simplified using [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html): `diff <(command_A) <(command_B)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IFS (internal field separator) to separate on newlines and store the outputs in an array.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='
'
array_a=( $(./a.sh) )
array_b=( $(./b.sh) )

if [ "${array_a[1]}" = "${array_b[0]}" ]; then
    echo "CORRECT"
else
    echo "INCORRECT"
fi
```